# Cheerio (node.js) returns an error on html read

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cheerio

I am completely new to JS, and got completely stuck at the Node Cheerio. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

The code I am working on is here: https://github.com/zafartahirov/bitstarter.

(The code that doesn't work will be called grader.old.js after the fix is found).

When I run

```
node ./grader.js --file index.html --checks checks.json | less
```

I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'utf8Slice' of null
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:416:26)
    at exports.isTag (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/lib/utils.js:15:14)
    at Function.filter (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3150:15)
    at /home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:9:26
    at Function.reduce (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3734:25)
    at exports.find (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:8:17)
    at new module.exports (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/lib/cheerio.js:92:18)
    at initialize (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/node_modules/cheerio/lib/static.js:23:12)
    at checkHtmlFile (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/grader.js:59:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/GitHub/bitstarter/grader.js:76:21)
(END)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I found a solution, but I still don't understand something:

    `var cheerioHtmlFile = function(htmlfile) {
        var buffer = fs.readFileSync(htmlfile);
        return cheerio.load(buffer.toString());                                                
        // return cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(htmlfile));                                                
    };`
I still don't understand why I have to convert the buffer to string though.

Comment: In that case, I strongly recommend reading http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely do!

Comment: You don't need to use toString on buffer if you call readFileSync with an encoding option, e.g., fs.readFileSync(htmlfile, 'utf-8')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are taking the same course, and it took me quite some time to debug it.
It seems the `cheerio.load()` method expects a String as an argument and not a buffer.

Comment: That how I solved it. I guess I got confused, as the "dummy"code did not have it in the comments, thank you tho!

Comment: Previously it accepted a Buffer object, but this was changed. I've opened an issue and will submit a PR if needed be: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/485